# Download de Imagem do Banco com ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou salvando imagens no banco de dados no formato varbinary.

```
byte[] arrayImagem = null;

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    novaSolicitacao.Anexos.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    arrayImagem = memoryStream.ToArray();

    aberturaOcorrenciaDao.EnviaAnexosDaOcorrenciaSustentacao(Convert.ToString(numOcorrencia), 
        arrayImagem, novaSolicitacao.Anexos.FileName, novaSolicitacao.Anexos.ContentType, novaSolicitacao.IdSolicitante);

    arrayImagem = null;
}
```

Mas não estou conseguindo recuperar essa imagem do banco e disponibilizar para download. Algo bem simples, uma action que pega o resultado em varbinary do banco e monta a imagem e retorna com uma action do tipo FileResult.

Meu retorno seria algo assim:

```
        public FileResult DownloadAnexoOcorrencia(string idArquivo)
    {
        var dao = new EditarOcorrenciaDAO();

        //Busca os bytes do arquivo no banco
        var arquivo = dao.BuscaAnexoEspecifico(idArquivo);

        //Aqui entra a função para converter esses bytes em imagem

        return File();
    }
```

Consulta do DAO:

```
        public AnexosOcorrencia BuscaAnexoEspecifico(string id)
    {
        var select = dao.conexao.CreateCommand();
        select.CommandText = "select * from TB_Ocorrencia_Arquivo where idArquivo = @idArquivo";

        var paramIdOcorrencia = new SqlParameter("idArquivo", id);
        select.Parameters.Add(paramIdOcorrencia);

        var resultado = select.ExecuteReader();
        resultado.Read();

        var anexo = new AnexosOcorrencia();
        anexo.IdArquivo = Convert.ToString(resultado["idArquivo"]);
        anexo.IdOcorrencia = Convert.ToString(resultado["idOcorrencia"]);
        anexo.NomeArquivo = Convert.ToString(resultado["nmArquivo"]);
        anexo.TipoArquivo = Convert.ToString(resultado["TipoArquivo"]);

        anexo.Arquivo = (byte[])(resultado["Arquivo"]);


        resultado.Close();

        return anexo;
    }
```

View que chama a função no Controller:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
            <label style="background-color: #eee;">Documentos anexados - Solicitante:</label>
            @*<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" readonly value='@ViewBag.DadosOcorrencia.PosicaoTorre' />*@
            @foreach (var anexo in ViewBag.Anexos)
            {
                <div class="col-md-12 row" id="@anexo.IdArquivo">
                    <a onclick="DownloadArquivo(@anexo.IdArquivo)" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <span>@anexo.NomeArquivo</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            }
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function DownloadArquivo(value) {

        var urlDownload = '@Url.Action("DownloadAnexoOcorrencia", "EditarOcorrencia")';
        $.post(urlDownload, { idArquivo: value });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Você quer "forçar" o download do arquivo? Coloca o seu código do return para eu ver como você está fazendo

Comment: Editei a pergunta @Tiago. Mas eu não faço ideie de como começar a montar a imagem com bytes rotornados do banco.

Comment: Não basta você retornar o stream do arquivo, precisa definir o mime-type.

Comment: o seu return precisa estar desta forma: return File(arquivo.FilePath, "image/jpeg", arquivo.FileName);

Comment: O que você guarda no "TipoArquivo", você chama o método `BuscaAnexoEspecifico(string idArquivo)` mas apresentou código da `BuscaAnexos(string id)`?

Comment: O código BuscaAnexos(string id) é a forma de chamar o método de forma assincrona na View. Ele recebe o id do arquivo para baixar.

Comment: E o que ele retorna? um `AnexosOcorrencia` ??? ps.: não tem nada de assíncrono em seu código

Comment: Corrigi o código da chamada DAO, (eu havia copiado o código errado). E inseri o código da view fazendo a chamada assincrona.

Comment: O retorno do DAO "Arquivo" é onde contém os bytes para montar a imagem

Answer (score 0):

Sua controller `DownloadAnexoOcorrencia` está incompleta.

Fiz dois exemplos de como você pode chegar ao resultado que deseja:

### Exemplo 1:

```
public FileStreamResult DownloadImagem()
{
    //Converter byte[] to Stream
    Stream streamImg = new MemoryStream(BuscarImagem());
    return File(streamImg, "image/png");
}
```

### Exemplo 2:

```
public FileContentResult DownloadImagem2()
{
    return File(BuscarImagem(), "image/png");
}
```

Meus exemplos são para imagem PNG, caso você utilize outros tipos verifique o mime type.

Meu método `BuscarImagem()` não é importante. Oque você precisa saber é que ele retorna um `byte[]` que é a imagem que quer disponibilizar para download, equivalente ao seu método `BuscaAnexoEspecifico()`.

[**Fiz um exemplo e coloquei no Github.**](https://github.com/Wurthma/RespostasSOpt/tree/master/Resposta_306099)

### Referências:

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2
2. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2